# Compare two list, and create other two lists with intersection and difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists A and B.

In the B list I can have multiple elements from list A.

For example:

```
A = [1,3,5,7, 9, 12, 14]
B = [1,2,3,3,7,9,7,3,14,14,1,3,2,5,5]
```

I want to create:

1. to create a list with ids that are in A and found in B (unique)
2. to create a list of ids that are in A and have no corresponding in B (unique)
3. Nice to get also: the numbers in B, that don't have a corespondent in A

My approach is two loops:

```
l1 = []   
l2 = []
for i in A:
    for j in B:
      if i == j
       l1.append[i]
...
l1 = set(l1)
```

I don't know if this is a good approach, plus remains the 2) point(what is not in b).

And I can't use `else on i!=j`, because of repetitions and no order in B.

Comment: Just use Python's builtin [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) type.

Comment: Please include the desired output in your question, because I'm really not sure if I understood (1) and (2) correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#to create a list with ids that are in A and found in B (unique)
resultlist=list(set(A)&set(B))
print(list(set(A)&set(B)))


#to create a list of ids that are in A and have no corresponding in B (unique)
print(list(set(A)-set(B)))


#the numbers in B, that don't have a corespondent in A
print(list(set(B)-set(A)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the list to `set` and then perform set operations

```
>>> set_A = set(A)
>>> set_B = set(B)
>>> list(set_A & set_B)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 14]         # set intersection

>>> list(set_A - set_B)     # set difference
[12]

>>> list(set_B - set_A)
[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

With python you can simply use the set type:

```
list(set(A) & set(B))
```

will return a list containing the element intersection between lists `A` and `B`.

```
list(set(A) - set(B))
```

Will return a list containing all the elements that are in `A` and not in `B`.

Vice versa:

```
list(set(B) - set(A))
```

Will return a list containing all the elements that are in `B` and not in `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14]
B = [1, 2, 3, 3, 7, 9, 7, 3, 14, 14, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5]

sa = set(A)
sb = set(B)

# intersection
l1 = list(sa & sb)
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14]

# differences
l2 = list(sa - sb)
# [12]
l3 = list(sb - sa)
# [2]
```

Comment: Isn't l1 = list(sa | sb) the union and l1 = list(sa & sb) the intersection?

Comment: Oh, yes that's definitely easier then my approach. chapeau!

Comment: @AlexanderPane I edited the answer upon your comment. That's what I meant by 'of course'

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yep, I was getting confused and I though I saw wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the 'a in L' functionality, which will return True if an element is in a List. e.g.

```
A = [1,3,5,7, 9, 12, 14]
B = [1,2,3,3,7,9,7,3,14,14,1,3,2,5,5]

common = []
uncommon = []

for a in A:
    if a in B:
      common.append(a)
    else:
      uncommon.append(a)
print(common)
print(uncommon)
```

this should give you a good hint on how to approach the other question.
best